# Prevent default keyboard from showing when UITextField is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Is there a way to make a custom keyboard to pop up when a user presses on a UITextField. I have a view with a custom keypad on it and I want that to come up when the user presses on the UITextField instead of the default apple keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

Since iOS 3.2 there's a property for exactly that, called inputView.

just go like this: [myTextField setInputView:myInputView] - where myInputView is obviously your custom input view. Then the system will pop up your view instead of the predefined keyboards.

Comment: Super tip @Toastor. This is very handy in few cases like when you have to load a date picker to enter a date etc. thanks!

Comment: setting the inputView to nil doesn't work, if you want the keyboard to not show at all. You need to make a view, even if its only 1 px square.

Answer (score 5):

You may set delegate in your UITextField and return NO in textFieldShouldBeginEditing:.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand the question? the keyboard type can be assigned to the UITextField so If you want a different one then specify it when initializing the object

```
UITextField * textFld = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType

Comment: Let me clarify. I have a view with a custom keypad on it and I want that to come up when the user presses on the UITextField instead of the default apple keyboard.