# How to disable keyboard when UITextField is tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

so I am building a car loan app which requires input from the user, they need to enter the price of the car, the interest rate and the number of years which they require the loan for.

This app has a custom keypad (like in a calculator) made up of UIButtons, however I need the keyboard to be disabled when I tap on a UITextField, I do need the blinking cursor (First Responder) otherwise the program won't know which text box to fill.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

I've tried to set user interaction to disabled but that also removes the cursor, I've also thought of using labels as well but that would look a little weird right, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to check the answers for this question.

[Prevent default keyboard from showing when UITextField is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175849/prevent-default-keyboard-from-showing-when-uitextfield-is-pressed)

It seems to be what you want

Comment: Thanks alot, much appreciated. Sorry I cannot vote up, since I do not have enough rep

Comment: You don't need to vote up, you can just accept the answer by click on the check sign on the left