# Dont show keyboard when textfield is tapped

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uidatepicker

I have a `UITextField` and a `UIDatePicker` in my XIB file, now I assigned the date that is chosen on the `UIDatePicker` to be the value of the text in my textfield. I've done this well, my only problem now is that I want the keyboard not to show when I tap on the textfield.
I'm sure somebody knows the answer, I will be glad if you will share it :) Thanks!

btw. I tried this, but it didn't work..

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175849/prevent-default-keyboard-from-showing-when-uitextfield-is-pressed

Comment: How about you disable the textfield

Comment: @Tarek, Thanks for the link, but I didn't wish to change the textfield's `inputView`, I just want to disable the keyboard for it not to pop up, because I already set the value of the textfield to be the one that is being selected from the `UIDatePicker`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just set the `UIDatePicker` as the inputView of your `UITextField`.

This wil repalce the keyboard as the input view when the user clicks on the `UItextField` with the `UIDatePicker`.

```
self.dateTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
```

Comment: As a side question to this. Is this all you have to do? Will the date picker then populate the textField automagically? Or do you have to take the dates and format them into strings yourself?

Comment: No you will need to handle the changes in the datepicker your self and format the date to a string to display it in the `UITextField`

Comment: OK, thought so, I have done this in the past just wondered if I'd done work I didn't need to. Thanks :)

Comment: @Fogmeister, I want my `UIDatePicker` to be fixed on the screen, hence I dont have to set the `inputView` to datePicker. I just want the keyboard not to show when I tap the textfield.

Comment: Yes I believe it will work, but the problem with this is that the `UIDatePicker` will only show when I tap on the keyboard. I already add the datepicker on the XIB file, I just want to disable the keyboard.

Comment: @chibimai then you should go with the answer by tarek, But i'm just wondering why use a `UITextField` at all if you don't want you users to click on it. A `UILabel` will do perfectly.

Comment: @rckoenes, it looks better than using a label. :)

Comment: @chibimai you could style the label to look like a `UItextField` or set even set the `userInteractionEnabled` on the `UITextField` to `NO`.

Comment: I already fixed it. I just have the idea pop up of my mind.. :) That's because of all of you. Thanks.. I posted my fix below.

Comment: @rckoenes, I also tried your advise and it worked! I think I would use it instead..

Answer (score 4):

You can set delegate in your `UITextField` and return `NO` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == YOU_TEXT_FIELD_TAG) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to make yourViewController conform to `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and also set `yourTextField.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't saw full answer, that I also needed, and come to solution with some answers here I'll put my code.

Simply put some "blank" UIView as input view.

Objective C

```
  UIView *hideKeyboardView = [[UIView alloc]init];
  self.yourTextField.inputView = hideKeyboardView;
```

Swift

```
let hideKeyboardView = UIView()
yourTextField.inputView = hideKeyboardView
```

Answer (score -2):

I already fixed it! I added the following code on the `viewDidLoad`

```
    [self.dateField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

and I still used

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Thanks for all your help anyway! Hope this thread will help others..

Comment: Bizarre way around it. You could follow either Tarek's or rckoenes advice. Just set the textfield userInteractionEnabled to NO. No code required. Just untick the box in the XIB.

Comment: @Fogmeister, you're right. I decided to use rckoenoes fixed instead. Thanks!