# How to freeze the editing of textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have taken a textField in a tableView. I want the user cant be able to edit the content of textField but can copy the contents.

I used the method textField.editing = false;
but it also disable the copying feature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920541/enable-copy-and-paste-on-uitextfield-without-making-it-editable

Answer (score 1):

Use textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    return NO;
}
```

Don't forget to set your textfield's delegate.

Comment: i also want keyboard dont pop up on its selection. I have made the textFields private to the cell so cant use resignFirstResponder in textfieldShoulReturn method.Any other way?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175849/prevent-default-keyboard-from-showing-when-uitextfield-is-pressed) will work. Try it with myInputView=nil or a fake view

Answer (score 0):

To disable editing in UITextField you need to return NO in delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

or you can do this also
    To disable editing in UITextView set property editable to NO:

```
[textView setEditable:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in viewwillappear method.

```
[textfield setEnable:NO];
```